# What does the '@>' symbol mean in postgresql?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm working on a project that uses a PostgreSQL database.

There's a few locations in the project which build queries like this:

```
query += " AND " + String + " @> " + String;
```

I'm not familiar with the `@>` symbol, and neither is anyone currently working on the project. Also [googling it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%40%3E%20postgresql&oq=%40%3E%20postgresql&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.18459j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=postgresql%20%40%3E%20symbol) doesn't work, presumably as it's an odd symbol.

Also, I'm not sure if this symbol is a postgresql thing or a sql thing.

P.S. The application in written in java.

Comment: Also please stop rolling back the edits that actually make this legible.

Comment: @EliSadoff I edited to something legible, the edits I rolled back contained *s etc.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but if you need to search for something that contains symbols, symbolhound.com can be useful.

Comment: @Mr.Llama Thanks! I've had this problem a few times now. Bookmarked :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's "contains".

If the column is array and use `@>` the column should contain the value.

More here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: It's not only used for arrays. It's also used for "contains" with hstore or range types